# What is the best practice/proper way to invoke an async method within a Parallel.Foreach?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm creating a .net core app where I need to call an `async` method to process a large number of objects. We have done this within a `Parallel.ForEach` so we can make use of parallelism to complete the jobs faster.

The service method is an `async` method which we cannot change. My question is what is the correct way to call this method when using TPL Parallel.

here is a simplified code snippet (i'm passing the iteration # instead of the object for demo purposes), along with our observations:

the `CallSendAsync` method internally makes a HTTP Request to an API (using HttpClient).

```
private void ParallelFor()
{
    Parallel.For(0, 100000, i =>
    {
        CallSendAsync(i).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    });
}
```

My problem with this above code is, it's using the `GetAwaiter` which makes the `async` method synchronous. However the above implementation is super fast. It seems to manage system resources more efficiently too.

On the otherhand I have this:

```
private void ParallelForWithAsync()
{
    Parallel.For(0, 100000, async i =>
    {
        await CallSendAsync(i);
    });
}
```

This code has an `async/await`. However it becomes very slow, performance degrades significantly. it opens a ton of outbound ports, and eventually the HTTP requests errors out.

Thirdly I also tried this:

```
private void TaskWaitAll()
{
    IEnumerable<int> arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000);
    Task.WhenAll(arr.Select(CallSendAsync)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Which also had similar results as the 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 3):

> I .net core app where i need to call an async method to process a large number of objects. we have done this withing a Parallel.ForEach so we can make use of parallelism to complete the jobs faster.

Let me stop you right there. You don't "use parallel" to "make things faster". Parallelism is one form of concurrency (doing more than one thing at a time), and it is a form of concurrency that uses multiple threads to process CPU-bound algorithms more quickly on a multi-core machine. However, your operation is not CPU-bound at all; it is I/O-bound, which is an indicator that Parallel is the wrong technology to use for this.

If you want to process multiple items concurrently when your processing is I/O-based, the appropriate solution is to use `Task.WhenAll`.

> however it becomes very slow, performance degrades significantly. it opens a ton of outbound ports, and eventually the HTTP requests errors out.

Yes. That's to be expected if you actually issue *one hundred thousand* simultaneous HTTP requests. Bear in mind there are less than 16k [IANA ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). For a massive number of requests like that, you'll probably want to limit it to a much more reasonable number - say, 20 at a time. `Parallel.For` will properly partition synchronous workloads based on CPU usage, number of threads in the thread pool, etc. To throttle asynchronous work, you can use a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```cs
private async Task TaskWaitAll()
{
  var mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(20);
  IEnumerable<int> arr = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000);
  var tasks = arr.Select(async i =>
  {
    await mutex.WaitAsync();
    try { await CallSendAsync(i); }
    finally { mutex.Release(); }
  }).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```